# Search value in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to search the value in an array. My array format is as below:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array([0] => [HEADER])    
    [3] => Array([0] => "ACCESSION #"
                 [1] => "F4216027")    
    [4] => Array([0] => "ACTIVATION CODE"
                 [1] => "PGMWZ-PUSUU")
    [5] => Array([0] => "CUSTOMER FIRST NAME"
                 [1] => "JAMES")
);
```

If I am trying to search `"CUSTOMER FIRST NAME"`. I tried with below function. But no result

```
function searchForValue($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val[0] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

And expected output is the key of parent index: `[5]`

Please help me to get out from this.

Comment: what have you done?till now? share some code!

Comment: @Santosh: Added the function which i have tried. Also tried with other ways as well..

Comment: you have error in array please fix it! Line : 5,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using `foreach` and `in_array` function:

```
$search_word = "CUSTOMER FIRST NAME";
$parent_key = null;

// $arr is your initial array
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($search_word, $v)) $parent_key = $k;
}

print_r($parent_key);  // 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still its giving me blank output. Still working  to find out the solution.

Comment: @sAcH, are you sure that you haven't missed something? because I used the array you have presented and it works well giving me `5` as parent key. Check your code for typos